# how to retrieve all data from sql server 2008 in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

how to retrieve all data from sql server 2008 to my page in asp.net this is aspx code :

```
    <asp:Image ID="ImageProfile" runat="server" Width="20" Height="25" />
    <asp:Label ID="LabelName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
    <asp:Label ID="LabelAddress" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

and this is my aspx.cs code :

```
    string cs=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM member",con);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    ImageProfile.ImageUrl=dr["image"].ToString();
                    LabelName.Text=dr["Name"].ToString();
                    LabelAddress.Text=dr["Address"].ToString();

                }

        }
```

but my output just one result whereas I have more than three columns 
thanks for any guide

Comment: Can you please paste the schema of member table?

Comment: You are overwriting the data in your field. So you need to take the grid, repeater, datalist to bind the multiple data.

Comment: As per your code, It will always show the last record. Use data repeater or some kind of thing to achieve this.

Comment: @Manoj thanks for your guide I appreciate I like this suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="ImageProfile" runat="server" Width="20" Height="25" ImageUrl = "<% # Eval("image") %>" />
        <asp:Label ID="LabelName" runat="server" Text = "<% # Eval("Name") %>"  ></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelAddress" runat="server" Text="<% # Eval("Address") %>"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In your C# code write this just set the data source to the repeater control

Answer (score 0):

Better place your labels and image controls inside a gridview template..so that everything will occupy in it..

```
SqlConnection con=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM member",con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds);
for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
{
ImageProfile.ImageUrl=ds.Tables[0].Rows[j][["image"].ToString();
LabelName.Text=ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["Name"].ToString();
LabelAddress.Text=ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["Address"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="RepDetails" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Image ID="ImageProfile" runat="server" Width="20" Height="25" ImageUrl = "<% # Eval("image") %>" />
           <asp:Label ID="LabelName" runat="server" Text = "<% # Eval("Name") %>"  ></asp:Label>
           <asp:Label ID="LabelAddress" runat="server" Text="<% # Eval("Address") %>"></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

    string cs=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM member",con);


       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
       da.Fill(ds);
       RepDetails.DataSource = ds;
       RepDetails.DataBind();
    }
```